# What is the scope of the word 'Augment'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

The dictionary meaning of the word **Augment** is to make (something) greater by adding to it. Is the scope of the word restricted to just quantity or does it extend to quality as well?

For example: '**Her secretarial work helped to augment her husband's income**' refers specifically to an increase in quantity.

But can the word be used like: '**He augmented the code by including XYZ compatibility**' to mean an increase in quantity as well as quality?

Also, is there a better word that can be used to mean an increase in both quantity and quality?

Comment: Why not? "... and allows users to develop commercial applications based on the code, or to augment the code for their implementations." https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1849803315

Comment: No. The dictionary meaning of the word _augment_ is 
    
: to increase the size or amount of (something)

: to add something to (something) in order to improve or complete it


:  to make greater, more numerous, larger, or more intense <the impact of the report was augmented by its timing> (If you use a better dictionary) (here, M-W)

Comment: I would understand _augmenting the code_ as including more lines of code, but not necessrily as adding quality or functionality. You can augment the funcionality of the code, of course.

Comment: I think I detect angels dancing on the head of a pin.  Has anyone been able to count how many there are?

Comment: @oerkelens While it may literally just refer to adding more lines of code, it will be generally understood that the _reason_ for that is to add quality of functionality. So the two senses will naturally be conflated.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm not sure that this is true in general. There may be dialects in which this conflation exists, but for many people, _augment_ is purely size-related. (I for one would _never_ boast about "augmenting" my code. Writing mny LOC is no longer necessrily a good thing!)

Comment: @oerkelens So when the answerer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9495189/2946161) says "**To augment the original answer...**", does he mean to delve further into the issue, to add more clarity to the original answer (both involve an increase in quantity and quality) or to just increase the length of the answer? Or is there a better word he could've used to express his intentions?

Comment: _It_ means he just increases the length of the answer, but _the answerer_ probably meant something else. As the answer to this question by bib shows, **enhance** was probably a better fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, consider the term *[enhance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/enhance)*

> Intensify, increase, or further improve the quality, value, or extent of:
>   his refusal does nothing to enhance his reputation
>   computer techniques that enhance images

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*